# How to make a filter to archive messages on "Promotions" category?

Tags: gmail, gmail-filters, gmail-labels, outlook

I use Gmail on Outlook (IMAP) and all messages from "Promotions" category are displayed on Outlook together with those from "Primary" one, and that messes up all my Outlook inbox. Is there a way to create a filter in order to archive all "Promotions" messages under a label (it would be a "Promotions" label) so they won't appear directly on Outlook inbox? It's important to mention that that filter would need to exclude some messages, in my case for example, messages already being filtered and targeted to go under some specific labels. E.g: messages got from Medium's website go to a "Medium" label, and the same to another ones, like Evernote, Google etc. I mentioned that because sometimes Gmail categorize them as "Promotions" I don't know why.

Any good ideas?

Answer (score 1):

From gmail > search bar > use the little dropdown arrow > add the following to the 'Has the words' section: **category:promotions** > click create filter > add you actions > save

:)